# What are the fields in the contacts table in android?

Tags: android

I would also like to know the RawContacts and Data table structure? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  ContactUtils contactUtils;
  private EditText phoneEditText, nameEditText;
  private Button saveButton;
  private Spinner mContactPhoneTypeSpinner;
  private ArrayList<Integer> mContactPhoneTypes;
  private String phoneType;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    phoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditText);
    nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    mContactPhoneTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contactPhoneTypeSpinner);
    mContactPhoneTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mContactPhoneTypes
        .add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME);
    mContactPhoneTypes
        .add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
    mContactPhoneTypes
        .add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
    mContactPhoneTypes
        .add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER);

    // Populate list of account types for phone
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Iterator<Integer> iter;
    iter = mContactPhoneTypes.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      adapter.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(
          this.getResources(), iter.next(),
          getString(R.string.undefinedTypeLabel)).toString()
      );
    }
    mContactPhoneTypeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mContactPhoneTypeSpinner.setPrompt(getString(R.string.selectLabel));

    mContactPhoneTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
          int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        phoneType = "" + mContactPhoneTypes.get(arg2);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
    });

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.saveButton:
      String phoneNumber = phoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
      String name = nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
      if (phoneNumber.length() < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.phoneNumberValidation),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if (name.length() < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.nameValidation),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
        contactUtils = new ContactUtils(this, phoneNumber, name,
            phoneType);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```